# Check value for every month in a year in T-sql using cursor

Tags: t-sql

I need a example of a cursor for my meter system, where the system reads the meter every month.

The cursor needs to check, that every meter has a reading registered in the current year. For meters with missing readings, an estimated value is added, such that the daily consumption is like the daily comsumption in the previous period plus 15%. In no previous period exiss, the above Kwh value is used.

Comment: What is the structure of your data and what have you tried?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.
My table contains of:
ID, Date, MeterNo, Consumption

Comment: First paragraph is month and second is year.   What does "if not prev exists the about Kwh value is used" mean?

Comment: @Blam - If there is missing a monthly reading for a meter, a defined value of kWh is used, if there is no reading in the previous month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this. (The MonthSeed table could become a real table in your database)

```
declare @MonthSeed table (MonthNumber int) 
insert into @MonthSeed values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)

-- assumes declared table "Reading" with fields ( Id int, [Date] datetime, MeterNo varchar(50), Consumption int )

select
    m.MeterNo,
    r.Date,
    calculatedConsumption = isnull(r.Consumption, -- read consumption
                                isnull((select max(r2.Consumption) Consumption from Reading r2 where datepart(month, r2.Date) = (m.MonthNumber - 1) and r2.MeterNo = m.MeterNo) * 1.15, -- previous consumption + 15%
                                    9999)) -- default consumption
from
    (select distinct
        MeterNo,
        MonthNumber
    from
        Reading, @MonthSeed) m
left join
    Reading r on r.MeterNo = m.MeterNo and datepart(month, r.Date) = m.monthNumber
```

EDIT FOLLOWING COMMENTS - EXAMPLE OF ADDING MISSING READINGS

As commented need to include an insert before the select `insert into Reading (MeterNo, Date, Consumption)` and making use of the left join to the `reading` table include a check for the reading id to be null ie missing `where r.Id is null`.

I noticed that this would result in null date entries when inserting into the `reading` table. So I included a date aggregate in the main sub-select `Date = dateadd(month, monthnumber, @seeddate)`; the main select was amended to show a date for missing entries `isnull(r.Date, m.Date),`

I've calculated the `@SeedDate` to be the 1st of the current month one year ago but you may want to pass in an earlier date.

```
declare @MonthSeed table (MonthNumber int) 
insert into @MonthSeed values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)

-- assumes declared table "Reading" with fields ( Id int, [Date] datetime, MeterNo varchar(50), Consumption int )

declare @SeedDate datetime = (select dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-12, 0)) -- this month, last year

insert into Reading (MeterNo, Date, Consumption)
select
    m.MeterNo,
    isnull(r.Date, m.Date),
    calculatedConsumption =
        isnull(r.Consumption, -- read consumption
        isnull(1.15 * (select max(r2.Consumption) Consumption 
                from Reading r2 
                where datepart(month, r2.Date) = (m.MonthNumber - 1) 
                and r2.MeterNo = m.MeterNo), -- previous consumption + 15%
        9999)) -- default consumption
from
    (select distinct
        MeterNo,
        MonthNumber,
        Date = dateadd(month, monthnumber, @seeddate)
    from
        Reading
    cross join
        @MonthSeed) m
left join
    Reading r on r.MeterNo = m.MeterNo and datepart(month, r.Date) = m.monthNumber
where
    r.Id is null

select * from Reading
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It is how I imaged it. 
Now, I have another question: How do I insert the calculated value into table Reading? It would be nice if it also could insert a date in the missing months

Comment: Well we can make use of the left join in the above query, and add a where clause to the end 'where r.id is null'. This will change the query such that only calculated ie missing, records are returned. Once you're happy with that query add INSERT keyword above the select.

Comment: Is it possible that you can show me that with code? Sorry, I'm new into this

Answer (score 0):

*(The following assumes SQL Server 2005 or later.)*

Scrounge around in here and see if there's anything of value:

```
declare @StartDate as Date = '2012-01-01'
declare @Now as Date = GetDate()
declare @DefaultConsumption as Int = 2000 -- KWh.

declare @MeterReadings as Table
  ( MeterReadingId Int Identity, ReadingDate Date, MeterNumber VarChar(10), Consumption Int )
insert into @MeterReadings ( ReadingDate, MeterNumber, Consumption ) values
  ( '2012-01-13', 'E154', 2710 ),
  ( '2012-01-19', 'BR549', 650 ),
  ( '2012-02-15', 'E154', 2970 ),
  ( '2012-02-19', 'BR549', 618 ),
  ( '2012-03-16', 'BR549', 758 ),
  ( '2012-04-11', 'E154', 2633 ),
  ( '2012-04-20', 'BR549', 691 )

; with Months ( Month ) as (
  select @StartDate as [Month]
  union all
  select DateAdd( mm, 1, Month )
    from Months
    where Month < @Now
  ),
MeterNumbers ( MeterNumber ) as (
  select distinct MeterNumber
    from @MeterReadings )
select M.Month, MN.MeterNumber,
  MR.MeterReadingId, MR.ReadingDate, MR.Consumption,
  Coalesce( MR.Consumption, @DefaultConsumption ) as [BillableConsumption],
  ( select Max( ReadingDate ) from @MeterReadings where MeterNumber = MN.MeterNumber and ReadingDate < M.Month ) as [PriorReadingDate],
  ( select Consumption from @MeterReadings where MeterNumber = MN.MeterNumber and ReadingDate =
  ( select Max( ReadingDate ) from @MeterReadings where MeterNumber = MN.MeterNumber and ReadingDate < M.Month ) ) as [PriorConsumption],
  ( select Consumption from @MeterReadings where MeterNumber = MN.MeterNumber and ReadingDate =
  ( select Max( ReadingDate ) from @MeterReadings where MeterNumber = MN.MeterNumber and ReadingDate < M.Month ) ) * 1.15 as [PriorConsumptionPlus15Percent]  
  from Months as M cross join
    MeterNumbers as MN left outer join
    @MeterReadings as MR on MR.MeterNumber = MN.MeterNumber and DateAdd( dd, 1 - DatePart( dd, MR.ReadingDate ), MR.ReadingDate ) = M.Month
  order by M.Month, MN.MeterNumber
```